# Substituting Ivy modules transitively

Tags: scala, sbt, ivy

I'm using Ivy programmatically (in the context of SBT) and I need to
be able to transitively substitute a small set of modules with a
compatible set which have a different organisation, but which share
artifact names, revisions etc.

To give a specific example, I want to replace,

```
org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.11.8
```

with,

```
org.typelevel#scala-reflect;2.11.8
```

everywhere within the dependency graph. Note that I only want to add a
dependency on org.typelevel#scala-reflect;2.11.8 if there is a
dependency on org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.11.8 somewhere in the
graph (which I don't know ahead of time), so it's not enough to
unconditionally exclude the org.scala-lang module and include the
org.typelevel one.

Is this possible? If it is, pointers to the necessary mechanism would
be very welcome. If it isn't, suggestions for workarounds would also
be very welcome.

Comment: While it's not a direct answer (therefore, I write it in a comment), I think it should be possible using sbt commands. I have slightly different use case, namely adding dependencies on the fly for the context of running a specific task, but it doesn't sound very different from what you want to achieve. I'll try to throw together a simple example for your case tonight.

Comment: Point is, if you want to do something crazy with sbt, use commands. http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Commands.html

Comment: I'm not working _with_ SBT ... I'm working on a fix for SBT itself.

Comment: FYI: in CBT this would be something like `def dependencies = replaceDependencies(super.dependencies)` where replaceDependencies does some recursive transformation of the graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using an Ivy `DependencyDescriptorMediator`. The following will perform the rewrite described in the question for `module` of type `DefaultModuleDescriptor`,

```
class OverrideScalaMediator(scalaOrganization: String, scalaVersion: String)
  extends DependencyDescriptorMediator {
  def mediate(dd: DependencyDescriptor): DependencyDescriptor = {
    val transformer =
      new NamespaceTransformer {
        def transform(mrid: ModuleRevisionId): ModuleRevisionId = {
          if (mrid == null) mrid
          else
            mrid.getName match {
              case name @ "scala-reflect" =>
                ModuleRevisionId.newInstance(
                  scalaOrganization, name, mrid.getBranch, scalaVersion,
                  mrid.getQualifiedExtraAttributes
                )
              case _ => mrid
            }
        }

        def isIdentity: Boolean = false
      }

    DefaultDependencyDescriptor.transformInstance(dd, transformer, false)
  }
}

val mediator = new OverrideScalaMediator("org.typelevel", version)
module.addDependencyDescriptorMediator(
  new ModuleId("org.scala-lang", "*"), ExactPatternMatcher.INSTANCE, mediator
)
```

You can see this in place in SBT [here](https://github.com/milessabin/sbt/blob/e98b2363c2779c68bca676171899a591370bb86b/ivy/src/main/scala/sbt/IvyScala.scala#L51-L86).

Answer (score 0):

While this isn't exactly the cleanest solution, I think you can achieve this by hijacking the project resolver (which is responsible for resolving inter project dependencies in SBT).

Somewhere in your build file:

```
// ...
.settings(
  projectResolver <<= (projectDescriptors, streams) map { (m, s) =>
    new RawRepository(new ProjectResolver("custom-resolver", m) {
      import org.apache.ivy.core.module.descriptor.DependencyDescriptor
      import org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveData
      import org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolvedModuleRevision

      override def getDependency(dd: DependencyDescriptor, data: ResolveData): ResolvedModuleRevision = {
        s.log.info("Resolving " + dd.getDependencyId.getName)

        // adjust your dependency descriptor and possibly resolve
        // from another source?

        super.getDependency(dd, data)
      }
    })
  }
)
```

This new project resolver could adjust certain dependency descriptors and then resolve them against the regular resolver chain... *I think*. You may have to override some additional methods.

Comment: Thanks. It turns out that Ivy provides a mechanism for doing what I want directly ... see my answer above.